# Drawing line of best on semilogy graph and showing it's equation

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I have some data which is related by the relationship `y = B*exp(Cx)`
I want to be able to plot the data and determine the value from the relationship:
`ln(y) = ln(B) + Cx`

I have raw data values of `x` and `y`.
I wish to plot them and draw a line of best fit on the graph and also display the equation of the line of best fit, to determine the y intercept which is equal to `ln(B)` and as a consequence determine `B`

So far I have this

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}
        \addplot table[x={x}, y={y}] {
        x      y
        0.284  0.01
        0.433  0.59
        0.485  2.97
        0.500  3.96
        0.531  9.48
        0.558  18.00
        0.597  45.00
        0.621  94.00
        0.696  1136.00
        };
    \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which plots the data, although on a log 10 graph not natural log as I would like it.

I have tried

```
\addplot table[x={x}, y={create col/linear regression={y=y}}] {data.dat};
```

but to no avail.

I am using an up to date version of pgf plots and the regression line does work if not on semilog axis.

Comment: I don't think that your code compiles without the pgfplots package and document class and so on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is just in the package you aren't loading in your preamble.  Taking your example (basically verbatim), and adding the appropriate package works for me.

Regarding the equation, you they are accessible through `\pgfplotstableregressiona` and `\pgfplotstableregressionb`, and we can convert from having `a x + b` to `A e^{B x}` by simply parsing the numbers.  Note that `\pgfmathresult` is gets written to all the time hence why I am writing it to `\fitb` as soon as I have completed the calculation.  If you instead had:

```
\pgfmathparse{exp(\pgfplotstableregressionb)}
\addlegendentry{Fit: \(\pgfmathresult e^{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x}\)}
```

then you aren't guaranteed that `\pgfmathresult` still contains the results of the exponentiation (and in fact, you'll find that it does not).

Here's the full example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
  x      y
  0.284  0.01
  0.433  0.59
  0.485  2.97
  0.500  3.96
  0.531  9.48
  0.558  18.00
  0.597  45.00
  0.621  94.00
  0.696  1136.00
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        legend pos=outer north east,
      ]
    \addplot table[x={x}, y={y}] {data.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Data}
    \addplot table[x={x}, y={create col/linear regression={y=y}}] {data.dat};
    \pgfset{/pgf/fpu=true}
    \pgfmathparse{exp(\pgfplotstableregressionb)}
    \pgfmathprintnumberto{\pgfmathresult}{\fitb}
    \addlegendentry{Fit: \(\fitb e^{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x}\)}
    \pgfset{/pgf/fpu=false}
  \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: note the difference that OP has an inline table you have an external file

Comment: @percusse Actually, OP has both an inline table and an external file, but he does not provide the external file.  I am *assuming* that the contents of `data.dat` is the same as in the plot (since he is wanting to plot a linear interpolation of that data).

Comment: I meant the difference between the working and the nonworking example

Comment: I'm guessing he wanted to add the linear interpolation on top of the actual data?  I guess we'll just have to wait and see what OP says.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I have concluded there was a different problem, I had 0's in my other data and as a consequence the regression finding algorithm was trying to log(0) which can't be done.
None the less, This doesn't address how to show the equation of the line

Comment: @EdL Sorry, I somehow missed that you wanted to have the equation of the line.  I have just amended by result :)